# How to Install LibreOffice Python on MacOS

Tags: mac, python, libreoffice, openoffice

I'd like to use Python to manipulate LibreOffice documents using the UNO API. I have LibreOffice 6.3.4.2 and Python 3.7 on MACOS (OS X).

I find doc which says UNO is available in the Python shipped with LO at:

- /Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/python

Not with 6.3.4.2 on MACOS, it isn't.

I see:

- apt-get install libreoffice-script-provider-python

Not with MACOS, you don't.

So how do I make UNO available to Python 3.7 on MACOS?

Answer (score 0):

Sigh.  Found it.  LibreOffice moved it to

- /Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/Resources/python